# Propensity matching issue in RStudio

Tags: r

I am trying to do a propensity matched analysis but am having a lot of trouble. I have a large data set with an exposure coded as 0 (no exposure) and 1 (exposure) and am trying to matched based on a couple of variables. Basically I was trying to follow a tutorial on propensity matching via Coursera but am getting a really weird output. My initial dataset has 2,202 distinct observations. However, once I do the matching, my dataset has 3,074 distinct observations, which is obviously not supposed to happen. It creates a matched sample, but I'm not sure where the additional observations come from...

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I have been trying to troubleshoot for the past week but keep coming up empty handed.

Here is what I'm doing:

````
race <- as.numeric(cohort$race_eth)
insurance <- as.numeric(cohort$privateinsurance)
language <- as.numeric(cohort$primarylanguage)
bloodpressure <- as.numeric(cohort$bloodpressure
bmi <- cohort$bmiatdelivery
exp <- as.numeric(cohort$prechange)
out <- as.numeric(cohort$tdapvaccinedate_yn)

#merge new dataset
propensity <- cbind(race, insurance, language, bloodpressure, bmi, exp, out)
propensity <- data.frame(prop_score)

#covariates to use in matching
xvars <- c("race", "insurance", "language", "bloodpressure", "age", "bmi")
table1 <- CreateTableOne(vars=xvars, strata="exp",data=propensity, test=FALSE)
print(table1, smd=TRUE)

#do matching
greedymatch <- Match(Tr=propensity$exp, M=1, X=propensity[xvars])
matched <- propensity[unlist(greedymatch[c("index.treated", "index.control")]),] # THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCURS SHOWING THAT I HAVE 3074 OBSERVATIONS ```
````

Answer (score 0):

it is not as easy to tackle your question, as your provided code snippet seems to have some issues before the error you report to experience, hence I was not able to reproduce your error. Still, I have created in the following a dummy dataset based on random numbers, and proceeded your steps. I have put down comments where potential errors could arise with your current code. Maybe this already helps!

```
#Indicate which Packages are needed
library(tableone)
library(Matching)
##Create Reproducible Example Dataset
# I create dummy data with random variables
race = as.numeric(rep(c(1,2),5)) 
insurance = as.numeric(sample(1:100,10))
language = as.numeric(sample(1:100,10))
bloodpressure = as.numeric(sample(1:100,10))
bmi = sample(1:100,10)
# it would be safer if you renamed exp as it is is also base function
exp = rep(c(1,0),5) 
out = sample(1:100,10)
#You did not inlcude here an age variable but will refer to it later
# did you maybe forgot to include it?
age= sample(1:50,10)

#merge new dataset
propensity <- cbind(race, insurance, language, bloodpressure, bmi, exp, out,age)
# In your example a new dataset "prop_score" appeared
# I can only guess you ment the just created dataset propensity
propensity <- data.frame(propensity)

#Input Dimension
dim(propensity)

#covariates to use in matching
xvars <- c("race", "insurance", "language", "bloodpressure", "age", "bmi")
table1 <- CreateTableOne(vars=xvars, strata="exp",data=propensity, test=FALSE)
print(table1, smd=TRUE)

#do matching
greedymatch <- Match(Tr=propensity$exp, M=1, X=propensity[,xvars])
matched <- propensity[unlist(greedymatch[c("index.treated", "index.control")]),] 

#Output Dimensions
dim(matched) #The Dimensions are fine
```

Comment: Hi Lea- thanks for your response. I added an answer with my reprex. It was too long to type in the comments. Does that help you understand the problem? I really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding! I did ur code and it still didn't work. What do you mean by "it would be safer if you renamed exp as it is is also base function"? I have attached a reprex for my dataset. Does this help?

```
outcome = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
exposure = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
insurance = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
language = c(3, 1, 1, 1, 1),
age = c(32, 36, 22, 26, 38),
bmi = c(23.8407, 25.354099, 29.709999, 26.9098, 36.290401),
race_eth = as.factor(c("5", "1", "2", "1", "2")),
nullip = as.factor(c("1", "0", "1", "1", "0"))
)

library(tableone)
library(Matching)

#recode variables to use in matching
race <- as.numeric(cohort$race_eth)
insurance <- as.numeric(cohort$insurance)
language <- as.numeric(cohort$language)
nullip <- as.numeric(cohort$nullip)
age <- cohort$age
bmi <- cohort$bmi
exp <- as.numeric(cohort$exposure)
out <- as.numeric(cohort$outcome)

#create new dataset
prop_score <- cbind(race, insurance, language, nullip, pnc, age, bmi, exp, out)
prop_score <- data.frame(prop_score)
xvars <- c("race", "insurance", "language", "nullip", "pnc", "age", "bmi")

#table 1
table1 <- CreateTableOne(vars=xvars, strata="exp",data=prop, test=FALSE)
print(table1, smd=TRUE)

#matching
greedymatch <- Match(Tr=prop$exp, M=1, X=prop[xvars])
matched <- prop[unlist(greedymatch[c("index.treated", "index.control")]),]`
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the `replace = FALSE` to your code

```
greedymatch <- Match(Tr = propensity$exp, M = 1, X = propensity[xvars], replace = FALSE)
```